# How to get values from arraylist Hashmap

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

How to get Value according to comparison. I am new in android and comparison is working fine but m not able to get value as it is displaying in arraylist. Below is my code and log-

```
for (Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : abbre.entrySet())
    {
        Log.d("Abbrevations values- ", entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        if(tid.equals(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()))){
        //String aValue = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
            Log.d("abbrKey Value: ", String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));
        }
        else{
            Log.d("abbrKey Key: ", String.valueOf(entry.getKey()));
        }
    }
```

The log -

```
   06-27 11:27:39.375: D/abbrKey tid:(13602): 27
   06-27 11:27:39.375: D/Abbrevations values-(13602): 23 [8+, 4+, 2-]
   06-27 11:27:39.375: D/abbrKey Key:(13602): 23
   06-27 11:27:39.375: D/Abbrevations values-(13602): 27 [8+, 4+, 2-]
   06-27 11:27:39.375: D/abbrKey Value:(13602): [8+, 4+, 2-]
   06-27 11:27:39.375: D/Abbrevations values-(13602): 22 [8+, 4+, 2-]
   06-27 11:27:39.375: D/abbrKey Key:(13602): 22
```

Comment: Do you want to compare arraylist values with hashmap?

Comment: no I need to get value when I compare its key with tid...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get values from Hashmap values(list of String),simply loop it and get all the values,So use your code  as

```
for (Entry<Integer, List<String>> entry : abbre.entrySet())
    {
        Log.d("Abbrevations values- ", entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
        if(tid.equals(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()))){
        //String aValue = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
            Log.d("abbrKey Value: ", String.valueOf(entry.getValue()));

         List<String> listValues = entry.getValue();
          for (int i = 0; i < listValues.size(); i++){
                String firstValue = listValues.get(i); 
               // similar get all values 
             }
        }
        else{
            Log.d("abbrKey Key: ", String.valueOf(entry.getKey()));
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you... this is working and I am getting all values but I need to get only that value whose key is being matched with tid.. can you please help...

Comment: what is the value of tid?

Comment: it is dynamic.. it is either 27 or 23 or 22 or any other number which user sends. tid have the values which is also in entry.getKey()

Comment: @user3705697 but at a time tid value will be one from them,and it will match with key only match.then it will print all the values only once.So my answer will work.

Comment: yes only one value will be sent to this method and will be checked and value be will be returned to the other method

Comment: can it not get only one value which is correct one as it still getting all values. please help... I am stuck in this code..

Comment: @user3705697 I really don't understand,please elaborate more.

Comment: If loop is comparing key with tid... I need only that value whose key is being compared.. i.e. if tid is 27 and key is 27, then it should only get value i.e. 8+ which have key as 27.

Comment: @user3705697 actually you got only one value for one key,its misundestanding because you have same values for all the keys.

Comment: I am getting [8+, 4+, 2-] as arraylist before for loop... in for loop firstValue prints all 3...

Comment: Because your hashmap value contains list of strings for key say 22 and that list contains those valuses [8+, 4+, 2-]

Comment: @user3705697 ok bro,enjoy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are using nested maps. so just `entry.getValue()` will give you list. as you are iterating over `Entry<Integer, List<String>>`

Hence to get contents of `List<String>` which is your value for `Integer` you will have to do this

```
if(tid.equals(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()))){
    for (String str : entry.getValue()) {
     Log.i("abbrKey Value:", str);  
         // iterating through values which is list in this case
    }
}
```

Hope this works

Comment: Hi.. thank you.. this is working and showing all values but I need to get only that value whose key is being matched with tid... can you please help..

Comment: If the code is working then please up-vote the answer :P
i will post another code in just a min

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the list you get in entry.getvalue() and get the values as below.

```
for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++){

}

for (String s: entry.getValue()) {

}
```